# Prove $ A \supset B , B \supset C \vdash A \supset C $

Tags: logic, meta-math

From Kleene's *Introduction to Metamathematics*, page 94 :

> "as further examples [of deduction] the reader may establish : "
>
> > $ A \supset B , B \supset C \vdash A \supset C $.

(Here $\supset$ means logical implication, not superset).

Comment: Any particular formal proof system you want to use? There at lots of different ones to choose from.

Comment: When you use $\supset$, do you mean implication?  What kind of tools do you have?  Do you have access to the Deduction Theorem (is this even a hilbert-style proof system or natural deduction?)?

Comment: Yes, I am using the symbol $ \supset $ for implies. And I do have access to the deduction Theorem and the 21 postulates. I am not sure about the style.

Comment: @GianmarcoSoldo: Which "21 postulates"?

Comment: For predicate and propositional calculus and number theory.

Comment: @GianmarcoSoldo: Generally if you want help with a particular proof system, you need to _show your axioms to the reader_, not just tell how many of them there are and/or what they are about. (In this particular case I'm pretty sure you have MP under some name, and that is all you need here in addition to the Deduction Theorem. Next time you may not be so lucky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't really need the deduction theorem: it just makes the proof easier.

Here is an alternative to Makholm's hint:

> 1. $A⊃B$, premise
> 2. $B⊃C$, premise
> 3. $(A⊃B)⊃((A⊃(B⊃C))⊃(A⊃C))$, Axiom Schema 1b (see p.82)
> 4. $((A⊃(B⊃C))⊃(A⊃C))$, 1,3, Modus Ponens
> 5. $(B⊃C) ⊃ (A⊃(B⊃C))$, Axiom Schema 1a
> 6. $(A⊃(B⊃C))$, 2,5, Modus Ponens
> 7. $(A⊃C$, 4,6, Modus Ponens

Next time make explicit your proof system in the body of the question:

This way you can get people who doesn't have access to the book you refer to help you too.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the Deduction Theorem, you just need to prove $A\supset B, B\supset C, A\vdash C$.

Use modus ponens on $A$ and $A\supset B$ to get $B$. Then modus ponens again with $B\supset C$ to get $C$.